# Trying to create a shape org, but getting ERROR: No such column 'PackageDirectories' on sobject of type ScratchOrgInfo

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, shape-org

I'm signed up for the Shape Org pilot and trying to get a shape org copy.

When I run `sfdx force:org:shape:list`

I get:

```
  ALIAS     USERNAME                            ORG ID              SHAPE STATUS  CREATED BY                          CREATED DATE
  ────────  ──────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────  ──────────────────────────────────  ────────────────────────────
  ShapeOrg  matthew.mitchener@dxorgshape.pilot  00D1I00000xxxxxxxx  Active        matthew.mitchener@dxorgshape.pilot  2017-12-04T16:25:27.000+0000
```

However, when I try creating a scratch org: `sfdx force:org:create -v ShapeOrg -f sfdx-project.json -a TestShape --json`

With this definition file:

```
{
    "orgName": "ShapeOrg",
    "sourceOrg": "00D1I00000xxxxxxxx"
}
```

I'm getting the following stacktrace:

```
INVALID_FIELD: No such column 'PackageDirectories' on sobject of type ScratchOrgInfo
    at HttpApi.getError (/home/mjmitche/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:250:13)
    at /home/mjmitche/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:95:22
    at tryCallOne (/home/mjmitche/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /home/mjmitche/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/home/mjmitche/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Looking in the org issued by the pilot program, the SObject for `ScratchOrgInfo` is missing a field called `PackageDirectories`. However in my non-shape pilot org, that field isn't available either.

Anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably trying to create it using your `project.json`. Try using a project scratch definition file. The file you're referencing `sfdx-project.json` should look something like this

```json
{
    "orgName": "Demo Company",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "orgPreferences" : {
        "enabled": ["S1DesktopEnabled"]
    }
}
```

usually it's called `project-scratch-def.json`

Comment: This was a long time ago, but I think you're right!